# Saving multiple rows

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm new to Cakephp and wondering how to save multiple rows with separator. This is the Controller:

```
if($this->data){
$array = explode(",",$this->data['Pincode']['pin1']);
foreach($array as $row){
     $this->data['Pincode']['pin1'] = base64_encode($row);
     $this->data['Pincode']['pin2'] = base64_encode($this->data['Pincode']['pin2']);
     $this->data['Pincode']['add_date'] = time();
     $this->Pincode->create();
          if($this->Pincode->save($this->data) ){
          $this->Session->setFlash('Saved', 'default', array('class' =>  'success-msg'));
          $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'managers', 'action' => 'pincodes?type=0'));
          }
          else{
           $this->Session->setFlash('Error', 'default', array('class' => 'error-msg'));
              }
         }
   }
```

When I try to post data and save them it only saves the first row.
The issue is that the foreach doesn't work properly.
Please help me with that. Thanks

Comment: After saving one record have you redirect or what happen?

Comment: after redirecting just one row saves.

Comment: can you try using $this->Pincode->saveAll($this->data);

Comment: @zynder Same result...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try with [saveAll](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-saveall-array-data-null-array-options-array) ?

```
if (!empty($this->data)) {
    $pins = explode(",", $this->data['Pincode']['pin1']);

    $records = array();
    foreach($pins as $pin) {
        $record = $this->data;
        $record['Pincode']['pin1'] = base64_encode($pin);
        $record['Pincode']['pin2'] = base64_encode($record['pin2']);
        $record['Pincode']['add_date'] = time();
        $records[] = $record;
    }

    if ($this->Pincode->saveAll($records)) {
        $this->Session->setFlash('Saved', 'default', array('class' =>  'success-msg'));
        $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'managers', 'action' => 'pincodes?type=0'));
    }
    else {
        $this->Session->setFlash('Error', 'default', array('class' => 'error-msg'));
    }
}
```